# custom modal does not appear react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I'm trying to call this Modal, but does not appear. I tried to put the Modal into a render() but it does not work too. I used inspect element tool and it shows the div from Modal but show it "grey".

This is the Modal

```
import React from 'react';
import './Modal.css';
const modal = props =>(
    <div className="modal">
        <header className="modal__header">
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        </header>
        <section className="modal__content">
        {props.children}
        </section>  
        <section className="modal__actions">
            {props.canCancel && (<button className="btn" onClick={props.onCancel}>Cancel</button>)}
            {props.canConfirm &&(<button className="btn" onClick={props.onConfirm}>Confirm</button>)}
        </section>
    </div>
);
export default modal;
```

and I´m trying to call the Modal here

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Modal from '../components/Modal/Modal.js';

import './Investments.css';

class InvestmentsPage extends Component{
    render(){
        return(            
        <React.Fragment>
            <Modal>
                <p>Modal content</p>
            </Modal>
            <div className="investment-control">
                <p>Modal</p>
                <button className="btn btnt1" >Crear </button>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>);
    }
}

export default InvestmentsPage;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Where are you calling it? Your button does not fire any events

Comment: it is working fine check the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-rdhlf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: it supposed to work because I'm following a tutorial, but my firefox and chrome don't show the Modal

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. I am guessing here your modal is hidden under some other DOM element. You should use ReactDOM.createPortal() for modals, tooltips etc. :

1. In **index.html** under the existing div with id='root' create new 
   div with id='modal';
2. In your modal Component as listed above **import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'** 
   and return 
   **ReactDOM.createPortal(*your_JSX_here*, document.querySelector('#modal'))**